# Find view in PlaceHolderView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an infinite place holder view (https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView) and my card layout looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/suTVJaeX) and java class [this](https://pastebin.com/3PeZmN01). Fields `imageView` and `category` resolved but `likes` TextView doesn't. The exception which I getting: `

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:430)
        at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:463)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6019)
        at io.onhigh.funtech.android.memorld2.ui.feedv2.dto.ContentView.onResolved(ContentView.java:25)
```

`

Comment: @Shashanth yes   --------

Answer (score 1):

your `likes` is of type `int`. Android thinks you're referring to the resource ID. It tries to look up the resource but fails to do so. A solution is to call `toString()` on the int `likes` property.

Comment: Yes, you goddamn right! Thank u